# if then else not seeing else argument

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I'm trying to learn myself some PowerShell scripting to automate some tasks at work.
The latest task I tried to automate was to create a copy of user files to a network-folder, so that users can easily relocate their files when swapping computers.

Problem is that my script automatically grabs the first option in the whole shebang, it never picks the "else"-option.

I'll walk you through part of the script. (I translated some words to make it easier to read)

```
#the script asks whether you want to create a copy, or put a copy back
$question1 = Read-Host "What would you like to do with your backup? make/put back"

if ($question1 -match 'put back')
    {Write-Host '' 
     Write-Host 'Checking for backup'
     Write-Host ''
      #check for existing backup
      if (-Not(Test-Path -Literalpath "G:\backupfolder"))
        {Write-Host "no backup has been found"}
      Elseif (Test-Path -LiteralPath "G:\backupfolder")
        {Write-Host "a backup has been found."
        Copy-Item -Path "G:\backupfolder\pictures\" -Destination "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\ ....}}
```

Above you see the part where a user would want the user to put a "backup" back.
It checks if a "backup" exists on the G-drive. If the script doesn't see a backup-folder it says so. If the script DOES see the backup it should copy the content from the folders on the G-drive to the similarly named folder you'd find on the user-profile-folder. Problem is: So far it only acts as if there is never a G:\backupfolder to be found. It seems that I'm doing something wrong with if/then/else.

I tried with if-->Else, and with if-->Elseif, but neither works.
I also thought that it could be the Test-Path, so I tried adding -LiteralPath, but to no avail.

There is more to the script but it's just more if/then/else. If I can get it to work on this part I should be able to get the rest working. What am I not seeing/doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked that `G:` is mounted and visible? `Get-PSDrive G`

Comment: Apart from the unnecessary 2nd `Test-Path` call, I don't see anything wrong with the code. Make sure you actually have access to `G:` drive. There could be an issue if you have mounted the drive as a regular user and try to access it from a PowerShell script that runs elevated ("as administrator"). In this case the drive won't be mounted for the PowerShell script by default. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/networking/mapped-drives-not-available-from-elevated-command

Comment: You test if folder `G:\backupfolder`, but later copy `G:\backupfolder\pictures`. Looks to me that is the folder you need to test. I would also add parameter `-PathType Container` to your Test-Path to make sure it doesn't return true if by accident a file with that name exists on the G:\ drive. Then `Elseif (Test-Path -LiteralPath "G:\backupfolder") { .. }` can simply be `else { .. }`

Comment: the G-drive is created on all of our computers. I figured I had a bracket in the wrong place causing a new backup-folder to be created even when you said you wanted to put a backup back in place.


@Theo, the 'pathtype container' seemed to help as well. Now to figure out why when I create a backup it only copies the directory, but not it's contents.

Comment: `Copy-Item -Path "G:\backupfolder\pictures\*" -Destination "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\..." -Recurse`. See [example 3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-7.2#example-3--copy-directory-and-contents-to-a-new-directory)

Comment: Thanks @Theo, I got it working. It now responds to the given answers and copies everything appropriately.